# Nested Stored Procedure in MYSQL has error

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

So I have this stored procedure, that I have tried to write a few different way, all to no avail.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `CreateHero`
(IN USER_EMAIL VARCHAR(40), IN NAME VARCHAR(16), IN GENDER VARCHAR(6))
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO HEROES (USER_ID, NAME, GENDER) 
VALUES 
((CALL GetUserId(USER_EMAIL)), NAME, GENDER);
END
```

I am getting this error

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CALL GetUserId(USER_EMAIL)), NAME, GENDER)' at line 6

I have tried tinkering with for a while.

GetUserId works. I tried to store the result in a temporary variable and then insert it but that did not work.

**Not to be shameless but** If you can determine a solution, a solution where the CALL GetUserId is stored in a variable would be best.

Comment: Is `GetUserId` a function or a stored procedure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use it like this. Rewrite your `GetUserId` procedure with an `OUT` parameter.

Something like this:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE GetUserId(IN p_email varchar(20), OUT p_id int)
BEGIN
    SELECT id INTO p_id FROM users where email = p_email;
    /*or whatever your procedure does*/
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Then your procedure `CreateHero` would look like this:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `CreateHero`
(IN USER_EMAIL VARCHAR(40), IN NAME VARCHAR(16), IN GENDER VARCHAR(6))
BEGIN
    DECLARE v_id int;
    CALL GetUserId(USER_EMAIL, v_id);
    INSERT INTO HEROES (USER_ID, NAME, GENDER) 
    VALUES 
    (v_id, NAME, GENDER);
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I dropped the old procedure, now this one is giving me issues CREATE PROCEDURE `GetUserId`(IN USER_EMAIL VARCHAR(40), OUT USER_ID INT)
BEGIN
 SELECT ID INTO USER_ID FROM USERS WHERE EMAIL=USER_EMAIL;
END

Comment: No, don't use the same names for variables and columns.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, yo

Comment: The procedure is just an example, I hope you haven't used it 1:1. And you have replaced my parameter names starting with `p_` with `USER_`, which are the column names of your heroes table. Don't do that, it'll confuse MySQL. Have you used appropriate delimiter? What's the error message?

Comment: I changed it to p_ and get the error #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3

Comment: CREATE PROCEDURE `GetUserId`(IN p_EMAIL VARCHAR(40), OUT p_ID INT)
BEGIN
 SELECT ID INTO p_ID FROM USERS WHERE EMAIL=p_EMAIL;
END

Comment: Please try again with setting a delimiter like in my edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

Old thread but could help some one looking for later...
Base on fancyPants answer but more beautiful like this:

```
 DELIMITER $$
    CREATE FUNCTION GetUserId(IN p_email varchar(20)) RETURNS int
    BEGIN
        RETURN(SELECT id FROM users where email = p_email);
        /*or whatever your function does*/
    END$$
    DELIMITER ;
```

And then:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `CreateHero` (IN USER_EMAIL VARCHAR(40),
    IN NAME VARCHAR(16), IN GENDER VARCHAR(6))
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO HEROES (USER_ID, NAME, GENDER) 
        VALUES (GetUserId(USER_EMAIL), NAME, GENDER);
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```